# field extension with degree of 2

Tags: extension-field

I need to decide if this following statement is true or false:
$\forall K \text{ field (not algebraically closed) } \exists L,K\leq L: [L:K]=2$

For finite fields this statement should be true, but I have no idea if this is true for all $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is false.

The complex [constructible numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number) are not algebraically closed, but they are quadratically closed (everything has a square root).

Comment: Oh cool, thanks!

Comment: More generally, if $K$ is any field (let's work in characteristic $\neq2$, so that quadratic extensions are necessarily Galois), you can form the quadratic closure $K^{quad}$ of $K$ inside a separable closure by the analogous procedure, which has no quadratic extensions itself. The Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(K^{quad}/K)$ is the maximal pro-$2$ quotient of the absolute Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}_K$. Thus, $\mathrm{Gal}_{K^{quad}}$ possesses no $2$-group quotients, which translates to $K^{quad}$ having no quadratic extensions.